# Add if to AJAX for Rails (check if this == DOM element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working with some JavaScript that executes a .post() function when a particular DOM element identified by id changes:

```
$.fn.subSelectWithAjax = function() {
  var that = this;

  this.change(function() {
    $.post("/people/thisguy", {id: that.val()}, null, "script");
  });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#this_guy").subSelectWithAjax();
});
```

`#this_guy` is a select element in a form. When it changes, it executes the .post function and directs it to the url "/people/thisguy."

I want to add an if statement to conditionally execute a .post function as determined by the id of the element for which the .subSelectWithAjax() function is being executed. I've tried it like so:

```
$.fn.subSelectWithAjax = function() {
    var that = this;

    if(this==document.getElementById('#this_guy')) {
        this.change(function() {
            $.post("/people/thisguy", {id: that.val()}, null, "script");
        });
    } else {
        this.change(function() {
            $.post("/people/anyotherguy", {id: that.val()}, null, "script");
        });
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#this_guy").subSelectWithAjax();
    $("#that_guy").subSelectWithAjax();
    $("#the_other_guy").subSelectWithAjax();
});
```

I expect the first .post function to execute when the id of the changed element is this_guy, i.e., direct to the url "/people/thisguy". However, it always executes the .post function specified in the else clause, which I've concluded occurs because the I'm failing to pass the right arguments to the equality operator.

Also, in JavaScript, does an if statement have to be syntactically valid to execute the else clause? I'm also trying to determine if what I've written is valid for some other check, just not the one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` will always fail, causing the `else` block to run, because you're comparing apples and oranges: you need to compare two HTML elements, or two jQuery objects, but right now you're comparing a jQuery object to an HTML element, hence they can never be equal.

```
$.fn.subSelectWithAjax = function() {
    var that = this; // In this context `this` is a jQ object, not an html elem

    if( this[0] == document.getElementById('#this_guy')) {
        this.change(function() {
            $.post("/people/thisguy", {id: that.val()}, null, "script");
        });
    } else {
        this.change(function() {
            $.post("/people/anyotherguy", {id: that.val()}, null, "script");
        });
    }
}
```

As for your last question, all of your code has to be syntactically valid, or the interpreter will not be able to run it, throw an error, and stop.

Comment: I've googled the this[0] you've used, but I don't understand how it returns the element as opposed to the jQ object.

Comment: Figured it out. `this` within the context of a jQuery function is an array of matched elements, matched meaning returned by the selector used. In this case, since we're using a unique id, there is only one element in the array, whatever was passed by id. So, you can access that first and only member of the array `this` using `this[0]`.